# How to select and compare the values in select query in then clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am Getting Group 1,Product,ID from `From t2 OI Join t3 OPL ON OI.c1 = OPL.P1 join t4 sp on sp.c2 = OI.p2 where sp.ID ='IQ')`
It works for Group1 and Product but with Id i am facing issue
I want to compare the ID with R.ID and then i need to retrieve the value
How can i do that?

```
 (SELECT Top 1 (CASE WHEN Group1='p'
             THEN (Case when Product='10'
                    THEN(Select top 1 Email from t1 as R join  t2 as E
                            on R.C1=E.E1 where R.ID=ID
                        )

                ELSE (Select top 1 Email from t1 as R join  t2 as E
                        on R.B1=E.E1 where R.ID=ID      
                    ) 
                END) 
    ELSE
    (Select top 1 Email from t1 as R join  t2 as E
                        on R.A1=E.E1 where R.ID=ID 
    )

    END) AS Email
From t2 OI 
                      Join t3 OPL ON OI.c1 = OPL.P1
                      join t4 sp on sp.c2 = OI.p2
                      where sp.ID ='IQ')
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: I am guessing that since you are using TOP this is sql server. But you have a logical issue here. You have no order by so you don't know which row you will get back. For the question at hand there just isn't anywhere near enough information to be able to help. You might check [this site](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) as a great place to start.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...